# Periodically copy data from one database to another MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I need to know how to copy data across to another MYSQL Server database periodically. I need something similar to MySQL events (database level) or a cron job.

**Example:**

- Copy data from database1..sametable to database2..sametable using a
  SQL command
- Run this statement every 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

In your mysql host machine:

```
1- Create a .sh file
2- Inside of this sh, put:
 - mysqldump -u myuser -p mypass mydatabasename > mydumpfile.sql
 - scp mydumfile.sql user@remote_host:remote_dir
3- Add that sh to a cron Job, to a daily execute
   (or something that meets your requeriments)
```

In the remote machine:

```
1- One sh script that look for a file(mysqldumpfile.sql) in the specific dir
2- This line : mysql -u remotemysqluser -p remotemysqlpass database < mydumpfile.sql
3- rm mydumpfile.sql
4- Add this sh on a daily cron 1 or two hours past the host cron.
```